# Is there a way to call the psql function without syntax error calls on ubuntu when calling multiple sql files in a directory?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I am experiencing issues with running this psql script on ubuntu terminal to map the mimic3 database to omop common data model, the code used is

```
psql "mimic3" --set=OMOP_SCHEMA="$OMOP_SCHEMA" -f "mimic-omop/etl/etl.sql"
```

the code stops running at the last truncate table command where it should call this sql script titled pg_function but it gives this error:

```
psql:mimic-omop/etl/etl.sql:28: etl/pg_function.sql: No such file or directory
```

I have attached a section of the sql file below as proof that it really exists:

[image: pg_function file]

The last part of the query has this code where it calls all the sql files listed in my screenshot below: 
[image: query]
I am following the instructions in this link:https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-omop/blob/master/README-run-etl.md

Comment: What is the value of `$OMOP_SCHEMA`? Looks like your environment variable is empty, in which case the SQL will be invalid of course.

Comment: I had previously defined the parameters by using the code: export OMOP_SCHEMA='omop'
export OMOP='host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres options=--search_path='$OMOP_SCHEMA

Comment: Are you sure that worked? Try with an `echo "$OMOP_SCHEMA"`.

Comment: Yes it did. It returned "omop" which is the name I assigned it to. Please see my updated question above. Do I have to update all the directories by putting the full root directories for each link? The new error says no such file for the first line (pg_function) and it really does exist

Comment: Wait, why did the error message change? Did you do something different, does the variable expansion work now?

Comment: Yes...I had run the variable assignment days ago and I am guessing it was not recognized so I reran them again. I have also included full directories for each sql file link so it runs now.